# What is SQL server LineageId?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have been using LineageId in SSIS packages but don't know the internals of it. What is SQL server LineageId? What's the purpose of it?

Answer (score 1):

- LineageID is a very important property in SSIS packages.
- Every column used in dataflow has at least one LineageID.
- It’s an integer value which identifies the column in the buffer.
- A column can have more than one LineageID and this is based on the
  types of transformation outputs  the column has (or passes through)
  in the data flow.

more info [here](http://sqlthreads.wordpress.com/2010/03/11/what-is-lineageid-in-ssis/)

Answer (score 0):

Every column used in dataflow has atleast one LineageID.
It’s an integer value which identifies the column in the buffer.
A column can have more than one LineageID and this is based on the types of transformation outputs  the column has (or passes through) in the data flow.